# ¿Cómo consumir una API y publicar los datos en un GRID php?

Tags: php, api

Estoy trabajando con una api, pero cuando quiero publicar los datos en un foreach me manda un error. este es mi código.

Este es mi json de mi API

```
[
{
pro_codigo: "PRO001",
pro_nombre: "Laptop Pavilion 2en1 14" Core i7",
pro_descripcion: "Laptop Pavilion 2en1 14" Core i7 8GB RAM 1TB"
}]





$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://localhost:49820/api/producto"),true);
print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $producto) {
   
    $data = array(
        'pro_codigo' => $product['pro_codigo']
    );
}
```

el error es el siguiente:
Notice:  Undefined variable: product in C:\xampp\htdocs\WS\test.php on line 23

Comment: En el bucle estás definiendo esto: `foreach ($data as $producto) {` y dentro usas `$product`, la cual no existe, prueba a  ponerlo así: **`'pro_codigo' => $producto['pro_codigo']`**

Comment: Aunque tampoco le veo demasiado sentido a tu `foreach`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr realmente? Veo que usas el `foreach` para redifinir el mismo elemento `$data` donde están de por sí los datos ¿?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, lo que quiero lograr es hacer una grilla con esa informacion de la API y tener un boton de busqueda, crees que sea buena idea hacerlo con el foreach?